# Is there a place to get an appraisal for a patent that is intended to be sold or licensed out?

Tags: licensing, non-obviousness, manufacturing, sellpatent

I am estimating that it'll cost me $5,000-$10,000 to get a patent on my invention.

The invention is a piece of manufactured textile wearable fitness garment.

If it is sold on Amazon, I'd estimate it to sell for $50 a piece. But if there is no competition (because of the patent), it could be sold for closer to $75, maybe.

Given this amount of information, where do I go to get an appraisal for the value of the patent?

Comment: What are you going to use the appraisal for?  I ask because this isn’t something that is usually done.

Comment: If you have a business plan with assumptions both with and without the exclusivity a patent can bring you could calculate a value from the net present value of the difference in profit stream over some reasonable time frame. But off-topic here.

Comment: You are asking about an appraisal for something fhat does not (yet?) exists. Really off topic.